# Find tag with certain child tag using bs4 python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an html in the below format.

```
<div class="consider">
    <div class="row">
         <p>Text1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="consider">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
<div class="Consider">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Text2
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the tag div only where its child tag(div) has class as "row"

Comment: $('.row').parent('div') something like this

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: Have your tried find_all ? `soup.find_all('div', class_='row')`

Comment: Yep fired but it only gives you the div with row. but i want its parent

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can access it :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = '<div class="consider"><div class="row"><p>Text1</p></div></div><div class="consider"><h2>Hello</h2></div><div class="Consider"><div class="row"><p>Text2</p></div></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='row'):
    if div.parent.name == "div":
        #do whatever you want with div.parent which is the element you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

With `select('div > div.row')` we select all div tags with class row as direct children of div tag and then through list comprehension we select all parents of these tags:

```
data = '<div class="consider"><div class="row"><p>Text1</p></div></div><div class="consider"><h2>Hello</h2></div><div class="Consider"><div class="row"><p>Text2</p></div></div>'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

divs = [div.parent for div in soup.select('div > div.row')]

print(divs)
```

Outputs:

```
[<div class="consider"><div class="row"><p>Text1</p></div></div>, <div class="Consider"><div class="row"><p>Text2</p></div></div>]
```